# Unity Facebook sdk 7.2.2 for iOS initializing false

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

Need help with the above post

I am using the below code for FB init in start

```
void Start ()
{
FB.Init (OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
}
```

and on button click i am calling the function CallFBloggin

```
private void CallFBLogin()
    {
        var perms = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);

//      FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" }, LoginCallBack);

        //      StartCoroutine (CallFBDelay (2.0f));
    }
    private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log(perm);
                //Debug.Log ("Fb User list " + perm[1]);
            }



        } else {
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
    }
```

I am getting the result as `FB.isInitialised = true;`
But getting  `FB.isLoggedin = false;`
even after authorising my app

Comment: Are you getting any error in result? You can add `if (result.Error != null) Debug.Log(result.Error)` to see. If you don't see any errors, then may be, I remember in some previous version facebook had a bug where the callback is called before `IsLoggedIn` is set to true, despite login was actually successful (I am not sure if it is still present at version 7.2.2 though). You can check whether it is this bug by waiting a second after callback, and checking `IsLoggedIn` again - if it is true, this is the problem.

Comment: hey thanks for your review but i am not getting any sort of error in my build even i have tried if (result.Error != null) but not getting any error log in debug and my isLoggedIn flag still comes to be false

Comment: Does this work with latest SDK and in the example project bundled with it? if so, that could be a good starting point for you to debug this